# Injecting a CSS/HTML loader into multiple parts of my site (html, js, vuejs)

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I have an animated loader made up of some html:

```
<!-- full page loading screen -->
<div id="fs-spinner-wrapper">
    <div class="spinner fs-spinner">
        <div class="rect1"></div>
        <div class="rect2"></div>
        <div class="rect3"></div>
        <div class="rect4"></div>
        <div class="rect5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which has associated CSS to get it animated. Currently I am including this HTML code at every point where I need the loader to appear... which is quite messy, especially when using it within vueJS components and other javascript functions.

Can anyone suggest the best way to be able to inject this HTML into each part of my site that needs it. In an ideal world I would love to use a standard icon approach, but am not sure if this is possible?

```
<i class="myicon"></i>
```

CSS:

```
/* loading animation */
.spinner {
    /*width: 50px;*/
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.spinner > div {
    background-color: #ececec;
    height: 100%;
    width: 6px;
    display: inline-block;

    -webkit-animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.spinner .rect2 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
    animation-delay: -1.1s;
}

.spinner .rect3 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -1.0s;
    animation-delay: -1.0s;
}

.spinner .rect4 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
    animation-delay: -0.9s;
}

.spinner .rect5 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
    animation-delay: -0.8s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
    0%, 40%, 100% { -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4) }
    20% { -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0) }
}

@keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
    0%, 40%, 100% {
        transform: scaleY(0.4);
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4);
    }  20% {
           transform: scaleY(1.0);
           -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0);
       }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your CSS too so we can see how it's animated? Maybe make a fiddle or use SO's code tool?

Comment: You said you're using vue, why not just make a vue component with the template? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Comment: I have added the CSS in above.